# Android 5 origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access while Android 6 works

Tags: android, ionic-framework, https, cors, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 framework to develop an application and encountered a weird problem.

I'm using HTTPS to communicate to my webservice and Android 5 mobile is throwing me *No Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header problem while Android 6 works fine by returning me a result.

Upon inspection this might be something to do with CORS and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header not present in the server config.

Android 5 HTTPS request header
[image]

Android 6 HTTPS request header
[image]

This is my content security policy at phone side:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

This is my function for https:

```
webserv()
  {
      var request = require('request');
      return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
          request({
              url: 'https://address,
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              },
            form: {}
          }, function(error, response, body) {
              if (error) {
                  // reject the promise, handle with .catch
                  console.log("Error: "+error);
                  reject(error);
              } else {
                  console.log(response.statusCode, body);
                  fulfill(body);
              }
          });
      });
  }
```

This is the error message
[image]

I'm guessing it's due to the origin is "file://" in the HTTP headers which is causing the problems.

I do not wish to change my server config if possible. And as this only affects Android 5 for me, I'm pretty confused in which where did I done wrongly.

**Update:** 
 Ran a couple of tests with other mobile phones and found out that I'm only able to support Android 5.1.1 and above. Version 5.0.1 (which is the original phone in this question) is unable to support still.

**Update2:** 
Enabled CORS in server config and apparently it works for Android 5.0.1 . But still do not know the underlying cause.